# Remote VS Code through SSH fails to start application with sudo privellege

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am doing remote development with VS Code and when I run the application in debug mode I get an error because it cannot open a file.
If I run the app with sudo ./app it is working fine.

I tried to ssh as root but I got connection denied.

Both host and virtual machine are Ubuntu 20.04.
The code is Rust and the piece of code that opens the problematic file is from a dynamic library, I cannot change it.

The problematic file: '/run/user/1000/dpdk/rte/config'

I spent the last 2.5 hours trying to find a solution but I've got nothing.
Let me know if you have any questions, thanks for reading!

Comment: can you please explain the following for better understanding `If I run the app with sudo ./app it is working fine. I tried to ssh as root but I got connection denied`. Does not this sound like SSHD is not configured for root access being the issue? If yes, check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` if `PermitRootLogin` is set to `no`. Convert to `yes` and restart sshd. Note this comprises security as you are allowing root login via ssh, use with caution. Let me know the results.

Comment: Explanation of the above quote: the app I am creating is developed on a virtual machine running on my computer. If I access the virtual machine in any way, through ssh or not, and I do sudo ./app then the app will successfully run. The issue comes when I connect my VS Code remotely through SSH and I hit the Start Debugging button. In that scenario the app won't be started in privileged mode and it will fail at some point. So I thought it would be a good idea to set up the ssh user in VS Code as root, but as I said it is giving me Permission Denied, even though the password is correct.

Comment: thanks for explaining the issue, can you please do the following 1. update the question to reflect the real issue as `remote VS Code through SSH fails to start application with sudo privellege` and can you check `https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48659` which talks about privilege mode too.

Comment: I did not know about the sshd stuff, I will try it out and let you know. I have high hopes on this one. (EDIT: I did not see your previous answer before posting this one). I will do as you said.

Comment: my mistake I assumed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67034012/why-rust-build-rs-is-unable-to-find-c-headers?noredirect=1#comment118526866_67034012 is related to your question too. If these are 2 different questions (running in gdb and running remotely with sudo) please ignore

Comment: I fixed the sshd stuff and managed to connect as root but one cannot run cargo as root and from what I have read it is installed per user, so root doesn't have cargo installed. As I said, basically I can run the app by doing sudo ./app but I cannot do start debugging from remote vscode. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: thanks for the update, to close this ticket either we have to cancel the ticket or update based on the comments. I will update with the result from comments. Please feel free to close the ticket by either accept or upvote the same. Or canceling the sasme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment conversation, the real issue is to log in as root `If I run the app with sudo ./app it is working fine. I tried to ssh as root but I got connection denied`. To do the same one has to set `PermitRootLogin` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart `sshd`.

DPDK application by default runs with privilege mode with `sudo`. This allows access to devices, Physical Address and files. One can also run dpdk in Virtual Address mode without sudo privileges too. For doing the same one needs to use `vfio` instead of `igb_uio`, ownership to mount huge pages, RUNTIME_ENV.

As updated by @Mihai `One cannot run cargo as root and from what I have read it is installed per user, so root doesn't have cargo installed.`  So the only solution is to run the application with non-privileged mode for DPDK applciation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately for me using the vfio is not a solution as I couldn't get those drivers going. But I found out that I could change the problematic file path from '/run/user/1000/dpdk/rte/config' to some path where I do not need root privileges. I am going to start a question regarding this path as it's more of a DPDK concern. I'll mark your answer as winner because it's the only useful solution given the question in the title.

Comment: @Mihai sure let me know if I can help in any other way

Comment: There's actually no way to run DPDK without sudo if one is using the igb_uio drivers. I know you mentioned it in your answer but I was too stupid to understand. I tried to do some little tricks to give ownerships to certain files but after that there comes a point where DPDK needs access to those Physical Addresses and that is the end of the road if one did not use sudo. 
It's even mentioned here: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/enable_func.html

Eventually what I did was to connect as root and install rust on root. For development purposes it's good enough.

Comment: So your answer is very good, thanks again.

Comment: @Mihai thanks for understanding, and best wishes